# Defining a wordpress page in a plugin, not in the sidebar

Tags: widget, wordpress

I am about to write a simple web portal in wordpress so it will be more web site than blog. I will create some static pages and menus the normal way. However, I want to control what is displayed on some of those pages programmaitcally. For instance, one page will show "Book suggestions". That page will be populated with a list of books the users have suggested. This list will be read from the MySQL database. Another page will be used to fill in some fields in a form that will be submitted and saved to the database.

I am new to wordpress plugin/widget developing but I was able to do this in drupal for another project.

So in other words, what I want is to develop a plugin/widget which will generate the content of some pages.

I was hoping you could help me with any suggestions or references :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you create a plugin and use the [shortcode API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API)  For example create two shortcodes,

```
add_shortcode( 'book-suggestions', 'book_suggestions_function' );
add_shortcode( 'book-suggest', 'book_suggest_func' );
```

then create a page called 'Book Suggestions' and add the shortcode

```
[book-suggestions limit=x type=y hotbooks=0]
```

and when the Book Suggestions page is rendered the shortcode [book-suggestions] is replaced using the returned value from book_suggestions_function().

```
function book_suggestions_function($atts) {

    // Parse $atts to determine limit, type, etc.
    return '<p>Book1</p><p>Book2</p>';
}
```

obviously you return data from the database.

similarly the [book-suggest] presents a form and POSTs the data to the database